# Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable (missing name) with resource ID even the resource is there

Tags: java, android, xml

On some Android devices, I am getting "Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable (missing name) with resource ID" error, e.g.:

On LGE Android 8.1 devices it is complaining

> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{SplashActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class ImageView

For the following part. In particular, it is complaining "**android:src="@drawable/red_logo"**"

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:src="@drawable/red_logo" />
```

I checked the source code directory, "red_logo.png" already exists in the following folders:

- drawable
- drawable-hdpi
- drawable-ldpi
- drawable-mdpi
- drawable-xhdpi
- drawable-xxhdpi
- drawable-xxxhdpi

Here is the Java code

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash); <---- Fails here
}
```

The dimension of red_logo.png in drawable folder is 4864 × 2692, same size as the red_logo.png in drawable-xxxhdpi folder. Is it too big?

I did a lot of research but it seems I cannot find a valid answer.

Thank you.
Best regards.

Comment: Which is line 20 in this xml file?

Comment: @RakeshSaini It is android:src="@drawable/red_logo" />

Comment: `4864 × 2692` - dimension of the image is too big while you are using it in the image view  100dp , reduce the size of the image . It's probably failing as device is unable to load the image

Comment: Yes I also think about that @Nitish. What is the recommended image size?

Comment: Try to make it below 600 X 600, Then you can increase by providing ImageView width and height.

Comment: Use - [Android asset studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/) , generate image/reduce size using `9 patch generator` , or `Generic icon generator` , you can supply with image size in `dp` , since you are using `imageview` of height `100 dp` , I would suggest you generate the image of size 100dp only(it will be approx. 408 x 408 for xxhdpi)

Comment: this issue happens also for me, I see the crash in crashlytics, I try to find same device with same os, issue cant be reproduced installing it from playstore

Answer (score 0):

It happens due to scale issues, hence, always use a vector asset instead of an image in such scenarios. Worked for me.